# OSGi Bundle is missing a dependency despite Embed all dependencies with the maven bundle plugin

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, karaf

I use the following settings for the maven-bundle-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
            <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>bundle-manifest</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>manifest</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And yet I get a "missing requirements" error in my Karaf instance when I try to start the bundle.

It's missing an `antlr.actions.csharp` dependency, do I have a way to find out which package/version is missing and why it is missing?

EDIT: The problem seems to be related to the Imported Packages listed in the MANIFEST.MF
As the imported packages list the package that is causing trouble.

Comment: Have you tried to look through your transitive maven dependencies? Maybe it is an optional dependency.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider I can only find antlr-2.7.2 in my resolved Dependencies from the Dependency Hierachy, it does not show a conflict with any other antlr version, but this antlr version does not have the missing packages as requested by karaf.

My Project runs with camel:run as well as with CamelBluePrintTestSupport, just not in the karaf environment.

Comment: What import package statements do you get if you leave the maven bundle plugin at default settings? (See Manifest of your jar)

Comment: If i leave it at the default setting and dont embed dependencies the import package statement contains a lot less and mostly camel related packages. The troublemaking package is not in there.

Comment: Also i managed to make the bundle run by compiling it without its dependencies and manually deploying all required packages, which if you subtract the camel features Karaf already provides, where only 4 jars.

Comment: This is a much better solution. Embedding is very likely to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Headers of the bundle should give you the missing dependency. Can you show the output of the Import-Package when you deploy it in the karaf instance?